# Accessibility issue on itextsharp merged pdf

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, accessibility

i'm trying to merge some fields using itextsharp library(v5.5.13.2) and test it with screen reader.
the pdf is Tagged but when i try reading the form using NVDA he cannot recognize the merged fields only the static text inside the pdf.
the pdf is created using Adobe acrobat Livecycle Designer and the textfields located in the "PDF Structure" correctly.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
enter code here

Dim OutputFileName As String = "" 
Dim OutputFileFullPath As String = ""
Dim FileName As String = "C:\Untitled4.pdf"
Using pdfRd = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filename:=FileName)
      OutputFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid.ToString("N"))
      OutputFileFullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\", OutputFileName)
      Using os = New FileStream(OutputFileFullPath, FileMode.Create)            
           Using stamp = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(pdfRd, os)
                    Dim fields As iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields = stamp.AcroFields                    
                    Dim Prefix As String = "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0]."
                    fields.SetField(Prefix & "MemberFullName[0]", "ישראל ישראלי")                                                                                                                                     
                    stamp.FormFlattening = true                   
                    stamp.Close()
           End Using
           os.Close()
      End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried iText 7 for it? iText 5 has been deprecated for a long while and non-security fixes are not going to be added there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the reason your tags are being eliminated is because of formflattening = true.

Whether this behavior changes with the current iText# library, I do not know.  But depending on what you are attempting to achieve, you may want to consider updating certain read/edit flags on the form fields you are manipulating.

I'm currently investigating a similar issue and am currently playing with the following attributes by creating an extension method to invoke SetField as well as tweaking properties:

```js
public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static bool SetFieldValueReadOnly(this AcroFields af, string name, string value)
        {
            // Add exception handler so return false is supported and usable
            af.SetField(name, value);
            af.SetFieldProperty(name, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Depending on the screen reader (and possibly settings) you may get different values called out like "edit+readonly <value in field" is spoken or "text " is spoken.

I don't like either option, but the key is that formflattening is set to false, which retains your accessibility flags, but exposes the form fields you are filling in.  I don't know if this will put you on the way to an acceptable solution, but at the very least this should provide a starting point for further experiments and commentary.

Comment: And apologies, my code is in C#, so I don't remember if extension methods are a thing in VisualBasic.  But the point is that instead of SetField and SetFieldProperty for every field you have (yours is in a loop so not so bad), you can combine it via one helper method to save some typing and clutter.

Comment: Thank's vincent i'll try your solution.